# Converting Binary PGM Files to ASCII PGM Files using Java? Using FileWriter gives empty file

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, filewriter, pgm

How can I convert Binary PGM Files to ASCII PGM Files using Java?

When I use the following code, I am unable to write ASCII values in the `B.pgm`. I've tried using `dos.writeInt` also.

```
FileInputStream inRaw = null;
FileOutputStream outRaw = null;
try {
     inRaw = new FileInputStream("A.pgm");
     outRaw = new FileOutputStream("B.pgm");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}

DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inRaw);
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(outRaw);
int i = 0;
String temp = null;
temp = dis.readLine();
System.out.println(temp);
dos.writeBytes("P2");
dos.writeBytes("\n");
while(i < 3){
    temp = dis.readLine();
    System.out.println(temp);
    dos.writeBytes(temp);
    dos.writeBytes("\n");
    i++;
}
int t = 0;
while(dis.available() != 0){
    t = dis.read();
    System.out.println(t);
    fileWriter.write(t);
    dos.writeInt(t);
    dos.writeBytes("\n");
}

 dis.close();
 dos.close();
```

I tried to use `FileWriter` instead of `DataOutputStream` and the code produces an empty file, I can't figure out why?

```
FileInputStream inRaw = null;
FileOutputStream outRaw = null;
try {
     inRaw = new FileInputStream("A.pgm");
     outRaw = new FileOutputStream("B.pgm");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}

DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inRaw);
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("B.pgm");
int i = 0;
String temp = null;
temp = dis.readLine();
System.out.println(temp);
fileWriter.write("P2");
fileWriter.write("\n");
while(i < 3){
    temp = dis.readLine();
    System.out.println(temp);
    fileWriter.write(temp);
    fileWriter.write("\n");
    i++;
}
int t = 0;
while(dis.available() != 0){
    t = dis.read();
    System.out.println(t);
    fileWriter.write(t);
    fileWriter.write(t);
    fileWriter.write("\n");
}

 dis.close();
```

Comment: In the DataOutputStream case, you don't want to be using `writeInt(t)` to write an ascii integer - use `writeBytes(String.valueOf(t))` - otherwise, it will write the data in binary.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you. :) Now I am able to write ASCII pgm files.

Answer (score 1):

(This might not solve your issue, but it will make your code much more robust).

One of the possible reasons why data isn't written to a file is that you don't actually close the stream - it can be held in an in-memory buffer until then, and is never written out. You certainly don't make an explicit call to `fileWriter.close()`.

You *can* try to close the streams manually, but it's normally unnecessary, and surprisingly tricky to do it correctly in all circumstances.

It is easier to use *try-with-resources* - this automatically manages your streams, and guarantees they are closed by the end of the block.

```
try (FileInputStream inRaw = new FileInputStream("A.pgm");
     FileOutputStream outRaw = new FileOutputStream("B.pgm");
     DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inRaw);
     DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(outRaw)) {
  // The logic to read dis and write it to dos.
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
// No need to close the streams - that happened automatically.
```

You can do similarly with the second version by substituting the `FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outRaw)` for `DataOutputStream dos = ...`.

---

If this doesn't solve the immediate issue, I would suggest that there is an error in your logic. Try stepping through the code with a debugger - make sure that the `write` calls are actually being performed.

Comment: I tried using the try-catch block, but still unable to write anything in the file. I used the following FileWriter constructor `FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("B.pgm")`. I'll debug as you told and see what is the problem. Thanks.